# How to "prompt" a subform for user input in VB?

Tags: vb.net, forms, prompt, subform

Here is what i want to achieve in my project :

When a user press a button, a form pop out with textbox, radio button and select menu on it, allowing the user to input their inform,

Click OK, the form data will be passed to some textbox in the main program form 
click cancel, the subform just go away

Is this possible in VB ?

I tried prompt and inputbox, but there are limited

I'm new to VB, so sorry if I didn't make the question clear

Comment: What don't you show what you have .. **but there are limited** ..

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way is declare a variable of the form you'll use then call the showdialog.  Now you can access all the control properties that are on the form.  Because you're using an object of form2 closing the form doesn't dispose of the object so everything is available.

```
    Dim NewForm2 As New Form2
    Dim Result As DialogResult = NewForm2.ShowDialog
    If Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        MsgBox(Newform2.TextBox1.Text)
    End If
```

In Form2 add this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this sample and cleaned up the code a bit:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103846-custom-inputbox/

I didn't know how to implement your radio button and select menu, but you can probably figure it out because the hard part is getting the text from the popup form to be passed back to the calling form and that is done for you here.  Let me know if you do need help with that part.  Maybe you could provide a screen shot of the UI?

So, from your calling form, click the button to show the prompt:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim result = frmPrompt.Show("The Title", "The Prompt", "Default", TextBox1.Text, False)
End Sub
```

And this is the code you paste into your custom prompt form:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class frmPrompt

Protected m_BlankValid As Boolean = True
Protected m_ReturnText As String = ""

Public Overloads Function ShowDialog( _
  ByVal TitleText As String, _
  ByVal PromptText As String, _
  ByVal DefaultText As String, _
  ByRef EnteredText As String, _
  ByVal BlankValid As Boolean) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult
    m_BlankValid = BlankValid
    Me.Lbl_Prompt.Text = PromptText
    Me.Text = TitleText
    Me.Txt_TextEntry.Text = DefaultText
    Me.ShowDialog()
    EnteredText = m_ReturnText
    Return Me.DialogResult
End Function

Public Overloads Shared Function Show(ByVal TitleText As String, ByVal promptText As String, ByVal DefaultText As String, ByRef TextInputted As String, Optional ByVal IsEmptyValid As Boolean = True) As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult
    Dim tmp As New frmPrompt
    Return tmp.ShowDialog(TitleText, promptText, DefaultText, TextInputted, IsEmptyValid)
End Function

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Txt_TextEntry.TextChanged
    If Me.Txt_TextEntry.Text = "" Then
        Me.But_Ok.Enabled = m_BlankValid
    Else
        Me.But_Ok.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles But_Ok.Click
    Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    m_ReturnText = Me.Txt_TextEntry.Text
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles But_Cancel.Click
    Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
    m_ReturnText = ""
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own form and show it with `.ShowDialog()` to be modal, like InputBox.

Then, when the data is entered in the controls, before closing the form, pass the data to your main form so it is not losed.